# DafnyLanguageServer: Can the function syntax version be configured?

Tags: dafny

Some background: I am using Dafny through https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends, which [requires](https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends/blob/master/emacs/lsp-dafny.el#L34) DafnyLanguageServer version <= 3.9.0, where function syntax 3 is still the [default](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/blob/v3.9.0/Source/DafnyCore/DafnyOptions.cs#L1011).

Can I change the `functionSyntax` setting when I am not using the CLI application but DafnyLanguageServer? The [documentation](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/tree/master/Source/DafnyLanguageServer#configuration) is silent on this topic.

The `DafnyOptions` type, where the `functionSyntax` option can be found, is [used](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adafny-lang%2Fdafny%20path%3A%2F%5ESource%5C%2FDafnyLanguageServer%5C%2F%2F%20dafnyoptions&type=code) in `Source/DafnyLanguageServer`, but if I can derive from this how to pass the `functionSyntax` option to DafnyLanguageServer, then I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand.

Seeing that DafnyLanguageServer takes parameters like `--verifier:timelimit=0`, I tried to pass `--verifier:functionSyntax=4`, `--functionSyntax=4` and `--verifier:functionSytax:4` which didn't work. Since [here](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/blob/ad7a358dbe33096bc26783b20762e071ab0c2a28/Source/DafnyCore/Options/DafnyCommands.cs#L80) I found `functionSyntax` in the "ParserOptions" instead of the "VerificationOptions" I also guessed `--parser:functionSyntax=4`, but, of course, that didn't work either.

I also found the `DafnyLanguageServer.appsettings.json` that is mentioned in the documentation, but there I didn't find a functionSyntax setting either.

I would like to avoid adding `{:options "-functionSyntax:4"}` to all my files. Unless this is considered a best practice?

Comment: If I am understanding question correctly you want to use function syntax 4 with dafny lsp server version 3.9.0 or earlier ?

Comment: In short, yes. An answer to the question could also help others to use function syntax 3 with newer dafny lsp servers where function syntax 4 is the default. More generally I would also like to know whether even more of the options of the dafny CLI (`--manual-lemma-induction`, `--disable-nonlinear-arithmetic` etc.) can be passed to the lsp server, but I guess the question as I have posed it should now focus on the function syntax only.

Comment: I looked into vscode dafny extension - this is how they are launching language server /usr/bin/dotnet dafny/Dafny.dll server. So they are not using DafnyLanguageServer binary. I am not sure how maintained DafnyLanguageServer is. But this way of launching supports --function-syntax:[3, 4]

Comment: I tried it: `/home/.../.emacs.d/.cache/lsp/dafny/v3.9.0/DafnyLanguageServer --documents:verify=onchange --verifier:timelimit=10 --function-syntax:4` (the other arguments are the default). Doesn't work :/ When I remove the `{:options "-functionSyntax:4"}` module option, I get errors.

Comment: Can you change dafny version to latest (4.0 or above) and try. --function-syntax option might not be added in 3.9.0 or earlier

Comment: Updating dafny would make part of the question (not everything!) obsolete, because I would get function syntax 4 by default. But I'm not sure if I can update dafny because the emacs mode ("plugin") currently [specifies compatibility](https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends/blob/master/emacs/lsp-dafny.el#L34) up to dafny 3.9.0 only. I can try changing that code later when I have more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, Dafny developers recommend using [dafny server](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-dafny-server) (instead of DafnyServer), which is a [Language Server Protocol implementation](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-dafny-language-server-vscode).

[Section 14.3 "The Dafny Server"](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-old-dafny-server) of the Dafny documentation explains that DafnyServer was developed before the Language Server implementation. It uses its own protocol to communicate with [Emacs](https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends).

As of 2024/01/05, the documentation says

> The Dafny Server is still supported, but we recommend using the Language Server instead.

but [DafnyServer does not support some recent Dafny features](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/4938).

As a result, the developers clarified the documentation:

> While the latest Dafny releases still contain a working DafnyServer binary, this component has been feature frozen since 2022, and it may not support features that were added to Dafny after that time. We do not recommend using it.

So it seems to me that you can't configure the function syntax version with DafnyServer and that it won't be supported in the future either. There may be a way to do it that I haven't discovered, but the more time passes, the more irrelevant DafnyServer becomes.

But actually the question is about "DafnyLanguageServer", not about "DafnyServer". The DafnyLanguageServer executable has been removed from the Dafny releases sometime between 3.9 and 4.4.

[14. Dafny VSCode extension and the Dafny Language Server](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-dafny-language-server-vscode) links to the [DafnyLanguageServer](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/tree/master/Source/DafnyLanguageServer) source, so I assume that the DafnyLanguageServer code is now used by the `dafny server` command. I was able to confirm that `dafny server` can be used in place of DafnyLanguageServer in boogie-friends' lsp-dafny.el: https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends/pull/41

To summarize: Probably neither DafnyServer nor DafnyLanguageServer can be configured in the way I hoped. But both are "feature frozen" or already removed from releases, so this part of the question becomes more and more irrelevant as time passes.

> More generally I would also like to know whether even more of the options of the dafny CLI (`--manual-lemma-induction`, `--disable-nonlinear-arithmetic` etc.) can be passed to the lsp server

The "forward path" of Dafny Language Protocol Servers, i.e. `dafny server`, fully supports all of those options, both when passed on the command line and via project files (`dfyconfig.yaml`).